# jvm won't young GC, s0/s1 won't be used and most instance are strings, how to optimize?

Tags: string, garbage-collection, jvm

I have a glassfish configured with the heap space size  `s0:s1:Eden = 2:2:8`. And I find that the jvm will not young gc

```
(! 22958)-> jstat -gc 1398 1000 100
 S0C    S1C    S0U    S1U      EC       EU        OC         OU       PC     PU    YGC     YGCT    FGC    FGCT     GCT
33792.0 19456.0  0.0    0.0   108544.0 108544.0  349184.0   348941.2  173568.0 173422.5  92634 1210.784 34932 20945.828 22156.612
33792.0 19456.0  0.0    0.0   108544.0 101252.3  349184.0   348941.2  173568.0 173422.5  92634 1210.784 34932 20946.499 22157.282
33792.0 19456.0  0.0    0.0   108544.0 108544.0  349184.0   348941.2  173568.0 173422.5  92634 1210.784 34933 20946.499 22157.282
33792.0 19456.0  0.0    0.0   108544.0 108544.0  349184.0   348941.2  173568.0 173422.5  92634 1210.784 34934 20947.106 22157.890
33792.0 19456.0  0.0    0.0   108544.0 74357.8   349184.0   348941.2  173568.0 173422.5  92634 1210.784 34935 20948.298 22159.082
33792.0 19456.0  0.0    0.0   108544.0 90966.8   349184.0   348941.2  173568.0 173422.5  92634 1210.784 34935 20948.298 22159.082
33792.0 19456.0  0.0    0.0   108544.0 96473.6   349184.0   348941.2  173568.0 173422.5  92634 1210.784 34935 20948.298 22159.082
33792.0 19456.0  0.0    0.0   108544.0 100628.3  349184.0   348941.2  173568.0 173422.5  92634 1210.784 34935 20948.298 22159.082
```

I believe that why young gc will not be preformed is that: the instance to keep alive size is more than the `S0/S1` size, 
So I dumped the heap and find that most instance is `String` or `char[]`
[image]

So How can I optimize this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Young GC is skipped if Old space is full (which is your case).

S0/S1 is irrelevant.

Increase old space and GC will behave properly.

Comment: finally, I increase the whole memory of the app to make young-gc happen(it will increase the old space too). will accept this answer since Alexey give the right hint that old space is full.